# how to achive expected output using DataWeave with data from a string inside a JSON

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

How to transform json data as shown in input into XML as shown in output using MuleSoft's DataWeave language.

Input

```
{
    "sponsors":[{
        "SP1": "John Smith",
        "NINO": "SC105012B",
        "INCOME1": 10000,
        "INCOME2":12000,
        "DEPENDENTDETAILS": "No, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, EduStatus, Income; 1, John, Smith, 12/12/84, studying at college or university, yes; 2, williams, Smith, 20/06/84, studying at college or university, No;"
    }]  
}
```

Expected Output

```
<sponsors>
    <sp1>john smith</sp1>
    <nino>sc15012b</nino>
    <income1>10000</income1>
    <income2>12000</income2>
    <dependentdetails>
        <no>1</no>
        <firstname>john</firstname>
        <lastname>smith</lastname>
        <dateOfBirth>12/12/84</dateOfBirth>
        <EduStatus>studying in college or university<EduStatus/>
        <Income>yes</Income>
        <no>2</no>
        <firstname>williams</firstname>
        <lastname>smith</lastname>
        <dateOfBirth>20/06/84</dateOfBirth>
        <EduStatus>studying in college or university<EduStatus/>
        <Income>No</Income>
    </dependentdetails>
</sponsors>
```

Comment: Please don't use the term DWL as it doesn't really has meaning. The language is DataWeave.

Answer (score 0):

DEPENDENTDETAILS seems to be a string of headers and records separated by `;` and each field separated by `,`. Once we split by each of those characters we can get a list of field names and a list of values for each records that we can manipulate easily.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
fun recordsToObjects(a)= do {
    var headers=a[0]
    ---
    a[1 to -1] map ($ map ((headers[$$]): $) reduce ($$++$)) reduce ($$++$)
}
---
sponsors: {
    sp1: payload.sponsors[0].SP1,
    nino: payload.sponsors[0].NINO,
    income1: payload.sponsors[0].INCOME1,    
    income2: payload.sponsors[0].INCOME2,    
    dependentdetails:recordsToObjects( (payload.sponsors[0].DEPENDENTDETAILS splitBy  ";") map ($ splitBy "," map trim($)) )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more option that you can try

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
 
var dependentdetails = payload.sponsors.DEPENDENTDETAILS[0] splitBy  ";" map( $ splitBy  ", ")
var keys=dependentdetails[0]
var dependentXml={(flatten(dependentdetails filter $$>0 map (
  $ map ((item, index) -> 
    (keys[index]) : trim(item)
  )
)))}
---
sponsors : payload.sponsors map ($ mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
if(key as String == "DEPENDENTDETAILS")(key): dependentXml
else (key):value
))
```